# LWC not able render Html JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, lwc-dom

Below is my requirement -

From Salesforce we are calling a service which returning a large set of html which include JS. When Copy paste same html(including js) in notepad++ and save it as .html file. its running properly as well as navigation using js working properly which means JS is also executing.

But when i call the same service from LWC using Wire Service and try to render using LWC DOM and Inner HTML, its not rendering properly and JS is also not working like show/hide etc.

please suggest a workaround

Comment: Please post the code as well.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The thing you're very specifically trying to do is not allowed for security reasons.

Comment: If its for security how it is executing/allowing in Visualforce page ?